# How to dynamically refer to vba objects?

Tags: vba, excel

There is an excel VBA form that has multiple dropdowns (over 10).
Those dropdowns are populated using code similar to this:

```
With Me.Controls("MyComboBox")
    .Clear   
Do
    .AddItem MyRecordSet![MyColumn]
        MyRecordSet.MoveNext
        Loop Until MyRecordSet.EOF
End With
```

Is there a way to dynamically set the values for the "MyComboBox", "MyRecordSet", "MyColumn" objects?

The goal would be to have all of the combo boxes populated in one loop, instead of having to have 10+ sets of the same code over and over.

The "MyComboBox" and "MyRecordSet" objects have similar names, but not the same.

Comment: Look at looping the controls, and getting the type, then using some tagging or suffixing or prefixing their titles, or good old if statements in the code, you can define them when the form loads up

Comment: dim c as control  for each c in me.controls  ...... next c

Comment: Just make a subroutine and pass them in as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim c As Control
dim s() as string

For Each c In Me.Controls

If TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
    ' HERE YOU COULD GET THE RECORDSET INFO FROM THE CONTROLS TAG??
    ' Or using Ifs or have the name as name_prop1_prop2.....
    If c.Name = "Dr1" Then

    Else

    End If
End If

' or

'  s =split(c.name,"_")
'  recordset = s(0)
'  column=s(1)

next c
```